# How to include the user credentials in every sidebar of very pages in ionic

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to have an sidebar that can display the name of the user who logged in. I have an account page that display all the details of the user. This is the code of the typescript below for the accounts page.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Headers} from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Storage} from "@ionic/storage";

import { Global } from '../../providers/global';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-account',
  templateUrl: 'account.html',
})
export class AccountPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              private storage: Storage, 
              public alertCtrl: AlertController,
              public global: Global
             ) 
    {
        //
    }

  public ACCOUNT_URL = this.global.url + "/api/inspectors";
  credentials:any;
  contentHeader = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json"});
  error: any;
  user: any;
  token_type: any;
  access_token: any;
  refresh_token:any;

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad AccountPage');
    this.getAccessToken(); 
    this.getAccount();
  }

   getAccessToken(){
    this.storage.get('access_token').then((value) => {
        this.access_token=value;
    });
  }

  getAccount(){
    this.storage.get('user').then((value) => {
      this.user=value;
    });
  }

}
```

and this is the code in my html.

```
<ion-header>
   <ion-navbar color="danger">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Account</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content class="page-account">
    <ion-card>
         <ion-item *ngIf="user">
            <ion-card-content text-wrap>
             <h2>Name: {{user.name}}</h2>
             <p>{{user.cellphone_no}}</p>
             <p> Address: {{user.address}} </p>
             <p> Email: {{user.email}} </p>
             </ion-card-content>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

What I want to happen is to delete the account pages and put the details of the user in top of the sidebar. So I have to put it into the app.html or app.ts but how can I define the property in my root component in order to display the details of that user.

Here is the code below in my app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import {Storage} from "@ionic/storage";

import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { AccountPage } from '../pages/account/account';
import { InspectionPage } from '../pages/inspection/inspection';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = LoginPage;
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any, icon: string, color: string}>;
  constructor(platform: Platform, 
              statusBar: StatusBar, 
              private storage: Storage, 
              splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });

      // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    this.pages = [
      //{ title: 'Home', component: HomePage, icon: 'home', color: 'primary' },
      { title: 'Home', component: InspectionPage, icon: 'home', color: 'danger' },
      { title: 'Account', component: AccountPage, icon: 'person', color: 'primary' }
    ];
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }
   logout() {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.storage.remove('access_token');
    this.storage.remove('username');
    this.storage.remove('data');
    this.storage.remove('user');
    this.nav.setRoot(LoginPage);
  }
}
```

and here is the code in my sidemenu or html.

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" id="myMenu">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="danger">
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
       <ion-icon [name]="p.icon" [color]="p.color" item-left></ion-icon> {{p.title}}
      </button>
      <button menuClose ion-item (click)="logout()">
       <ion-icon name="log-out" color="default" item-left></ion-icon> Logout
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<!-- Disable swipe-to-go-back because it's poor UX to combine STGB with side menus -->
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

What I want to happen is to put the details of the user in the sidebar like what I did in the account page. Sorry for my long question. I tried searching for it but can't find any answer to it.

Looking for help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you create a service to handle the state of the user login. That way the state is handled in a central place and it will be much easier to maintain.

One possible approach would be to use a `BehaviourSubject` inside your service, which you can then subscribe to on every page that you need your user object (like your account page and your app component).

```
import {Injectable}      from '@angular/core'
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  // Observable user object (replace any with your user class/interface)
  private _userObject = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});

  // Expose an observable that can be used by components
  userObject$ = this._userObject.asObservable();

  // Method to update the user
  changeUser(user) {
    this._userObject.next(user);
  }
}
```

You can now use the service like that (you have to implement the subscription logic in every component where you want to have access to your user):

```
import {Component}    from '@angular/core';
import {UserService}   from './user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'account-page'
})
export class AccountPage {
  user: any;
  subscription: Subscription;
  constructor(private _userService: UserService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this._userService.userObject$
       .subscribe(item => this.user = item);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // prevent memory leak when component is destroyed
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  login() {
    this._userService.changeUser({
      name: 'Name' // Replace with name / user object
    });
  }

  logout() {
    this._userService.changeUser({});
  }
}
```

As mentioned above, the big advantage is maintainability. If you ever change your user object, it only requires minimal changes, whereas the solution by @Tomislav Stankovic requires changes in every component where the user is used.

Answer (score 1):

In your **login page**, when user is successfully logged-in, store data to localStorage

```
login(username,password){
     this._api.userLogin().subscribe(res => {

      if(res.status == 'ok'){
      localStorage.setItem('user_first_name', res.user_first_name);
      localStorage.setItem('user_last_name', res.user_last_name);

     }
}
```

And then in **app.component.ts** get data from localStorage

```
this.first_name = localStorage.getItem('user_first_name');
this.last_name = localStorage.getItem('user_last_name');
```

Display data in **app.html**

```
  <p>{{first_name}}</p> 
   <p>{{last_name}}</p>
```

On **log-out** clear localStorage

```
logout(){
  localStorage.clear();
}
```